# tkz-euclide: How to modify the size and color of the point in \tkzMarkRightAngle[german]?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

To mark right angles I use the macro `\tkzMarkRightAngle[german]` from `tkz-euclide`.

How can I modify the size and color of the point?

**Screenshot without zoom**

[image]

**Screenshot with zoom**

[image]

**MWE**

```
begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=-90]
\tkzDefPoint(0,1){A}
\tkzDefPoint(2,4){C}
\tkzDefPointWith[orthogonal normed,K=7](C,A)
\tkzGetPoint{B}
\tkzDrawSegment[green!60!black](A,C)
\tkzDrawSegment[green!60!black](C,B)
\tkzDrawSegment[green!60!black](B,A)
\tkzDrawLine[altitude,dashed,color=magenta](B,C,A)
\tkzGetPoint{P}
\tkzLabelPoint[left](A){$A$}
\tkzLabelPoint[right](B){$B$}
\tkzLabelPoint[above](C){$C$}
\tkzLabelPoint[left](P){$P$}
\tkzLabelSegment[auto](B,A){$c$}
\tkzLabelSegment[auto,swap](B,C){$a$}
\tkzLabelSegment[auto,swap](C,A){$b$}
\tkzMarkAngle[size=1cm,color=cyan,mark=|](C,B,A)
\tkzMarkAngle[size=1cm,color=cyan,mark=|](A,C,P)
\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.75cm,color=orange,mark=||](P,C,B)
\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.75cm,color=orange,mark=||](B,A,C)
\tkzMarkRightAngle[german](A,C,B)
\tkzMarkRightAngle[german](B,P,C)
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the dot size there is an undocumented key `dotsize` that can be provided to `\tkzMarkRightAngle`, with a default value of `3pt`.

For the color there is no key, but you can add your own key using `\pgfkeys`. In order to use the key, the code used for drawing the angle needs to be patched, which can be done with the package `xpatch`. The `\tkzMarkRightAngle` command internally calls the `\tkz@RightAngle` command, so that command needs to be patched. Because the command name contains an `@` symbol the code for patching and introducing the internal key (which for consistency I have named `\tkz@ra@dotsize`, so also containing `@`) needs to be surrounded by `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{/tkzrightangle/.cd,
    dotcolor/.store in = \tkz@ra@dotcolor, % set internal key
    dotcolor = black} % default value
% insert color=\tkz@ra@dotcolor in original drawing command
\xpatchcmd{\tkz@RightAngle}{node[fill,circle,minimum size=\tkz@dotsize,inner sep=0 pt]}{node[fill,color=\tkz@ra@dotcolor,circle,minimum size=\tkz@dotsize,inner sep=0 pt]}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=-90]
\tkzDefPoint(0,1){A}
\tkzDefPoint(2,4){C}
\tkzDefPointWith[orthogonal normed,K=7](C,A)
\tkzGetPoint{B}
\tkzDrawSegment[green!60!black](A,C)
\tkzDrawSegment[green!60!black](C,B)
\tkzDrawSegment[green!60!black](B,A)
\tkzDrawLine[altitude,dashed,color=magenta](B,C,A)
\tkzGetPoint{P}
\tkzLabelPoint[left](A){$A$}
\tkzLabelPoint[right](B){$B$}
\tkzLabelPoint[above](C){$C$}
\tkzLabelPoint[left](P){$P$}
\tkzLabelSegment[auto](B,A){$c$}
\tkzLabelSegment[auto,swap](B,C){$a$}
\tkzLabelSegment[auto,swap](C,A){$b$}
\tkzMarkAngle[size=1cm,color=cyan,mark=|](C,B,A)
\tkzMarkAngle[size=1cm,color=cyan,mark=|](A,C,P)
\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.75cm,color=orange,mark=||](P,C,B)
\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.75cm,color=orange,mark=||](B,A,C)
\tkzMarkRightAngle[german](A,C,B)
\tkzMarkRightAngle[german,dotsize=5pt,dotcolor=blue](B,P,C)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Nice solution! Maybe the package author can implement this.

Comment: @Sr.Schneider I forgot. `/tkzrightangle/.cd,#1` inside      `node[fill,circle,minimum size=\tkz@dotsize,  inner sep=0 pt,/tkzrightangle/.cd,#1] {};`. The arc and the point are the same colour with  `\tkzMarkRightAngle[german,size=1,dotsize=5pt,blue](B,P,C) `